# Look for all files named temp

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I’m supposed to look for all files named `temp`. 
Would I just do: `find . -name "temp"`

Then I’m supposed to make sure no error messages pop up 
Would I just add the `2>/dev/null` at the end of the previous command?

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it work?

Comment: You're heading down a dangerous path: [A Temporary Problem](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/A-Temporary-Problem)

Comment: yes the (find . -name temp -type f) worked. However, now I'm supposed to put the error messages that come up when i search for files named temp into /dev/null using 2> so would it be  find . -name temp -type f 2> /dev/null ?

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
find . -name temp
```

would find all *names* that are `temp`.  This includes all sorts of files, e.g. regular files, directories, sockets, symbolic links etc.

If you want to find only *regular* files, then use the `-type f` test:

```
find . -name temp -type f
```

To hide the errors that this may provoke (by trying to access inaccessible directories):

```
find . -name temp -type f 2>/dev/null
```

That is, redirect the standard error stream of `find` to `/dev/null` (which discards all errors).

If you want to avoid errors, i.e. not *hide* errors, then make sure that you don't try to enter directories that you don't have access to.  With GNU `find`, this may conveniently be done using

```
find . -type d ! \( -readable -executable \) -prune -o -name temp -type f -print
```

The `-type d` test will be true for any directory, and with GNU `find`, the negated `-executable -readable` test will be true if the current pathname refers to a thing that is not both executable and readable for the current user.  A directory is *accessible* if it is executable by you, and you can list a directory's contents if it's also readable.  The `-prune` "prunes" the directory from the search tree, i.e. it makes `find` not enter it.

The `-o` is a logical "OR" operation.  When `-o` is not used, the default is `-a` for "AND". The tests and actions specified are evaluated in a left-to-right manner.

The final `-print` prints out all pathnames that passes all the tests.

Would you want to *do* something to the found files, then do so with an action executed by `find`.  To delete them, for example, add `-delete` to the end of the command (or change `-print` to `-delete`).  To do a more generic action, you may want to loop over them. You do that using

```
find . -type d ! \( -readable -executable \) -prune -o -name temp -type f \
    -exec sh -c '
        for pathname do
            # code that uses "$pathname" goes here
        done' sh {} +
```

See also

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)